# How can I create a generic method to compare two list of any type. The type may be a List of class as well

Tags: c#, list, generics

Following is a class

```
public class Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Following is the code in my main method

```
{
            var test = new List<Attribute>();
            test.Add(new Attribute { Name = "Don", Value = "21" });
            test.Add(new Attribute { Value = "34", Name = "Karthik" });


            var test1 = new List<Attribute>();
            test1.Add(new Attribute { Name = "Don", Value = "21" });
            test1.Add(new Attribute { Value = "34", Name = "Karthik" });

            var obj = new Program();
            var areEqual1 = obj.CompareList<List<Attribute>>(test, test1);
}
```

I have a ComapreList method

```
public bool CompareList<T>(T firstList, T secondList) where T : class
        {
            var list1 = firstList as IList<T>;

            return true;

        }
```

Now, list1 has null. I know that .net does not allow us to do this. But is there any other way where I can cast this generic list. My purpose is to compare each property value of these two list. I am using reflection to get the property but it works only if I can convert the firstlist/secondlist to something enumerable. if I directly use the name of the class in the `IList<>` (`firstList` as `IList<Attribute>`) it works, but not if I give `<T>`. Please help.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Just create method parameterized by type of lists items type. Even more, you can create method which compares any type of collections:

```
public bool CompareSequences<T> (IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second,
      Comparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

    if (first == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));

    if (second == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));

    var firstIterator = first.GetEnumerator();
    var secondIterator = second.GetEnumerator();

    while(true)
    {
        bool firstHasItem = firstIterator.MoveNext();
        bool secondHasItem = secondIterator.MoveNext();

        if (firstHasItem != secondHasItem)
            return false;

        if (!firstHasItem && !secondHasItem)
            return true;

        if (comparer.Compare(firstIterator.Current, secondIterator.Current) != 0)
            return false;
    }
}
```

If collection items are primitive types, you can use default comparer. But if collections contain custom items, you need either `IComparable` to be implemented by collection items type:

```
public class Attribute : IComparable<Attribute>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo (Attribute other)
    {
        int result = Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
        if (result == 0)
            return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Or you can create and pass comparer instance. You can create comparer which is using reflection to compare fields/properties of some type. But it's not as simple as you might think - properties can be complex type or collections.

Usage:

```
var areEqual1 = obj.CompareSequences(test, test1);
```

---

If you don't need to compare objects with complex structure (which have inner collections and other custom objects) then you can use comparer like this one:

```
public class SimplePropertiesComparer<T> : Comparer<T>
{
    public override int Compare (T x, T y)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var flags = BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties(flags))
        {
            var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            if (!typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
               throw new NotSupportedException($"{propertyType} props are not supported.");

            var propertyValueX = (IComparable)property.GetValue(x);
            var propertyValueY = (IComparable)property.GetValue(y);

            if (propertyValueX == null && propertyValueY == null)
                continue;

            if (propertyValueX == null)
                return -1;

            int result = propertyValueX.CompareTo(property.GetValue(y));
            if (result == 0)
                continue;

            return result;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

And pass it to sequence comparer

```
var equal = obj.CompareSequences(test, test1, new SimplePropertiesComparer<Attribute>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of your method and remove the then redundant cast:

```
public bool CompareList<T>(IList<T> firstList, IList<T> secondList) where T : class
{
    var list1 = firstList as IList<T>; // Cast is not necessary any more
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have done what you have suggested but than when I call the CompareList method it say something like this "The type Generic,List<Attribute> cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method"

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool CompareGenericLists<T, U>(List<T> list1, List<U> list2)
    {
        try
        {

            if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(U)))
            {
                //For checking null lists
                if (list1 == null && list2 == null)
                    return true;
                if (list1 == null || list2 == null)
                    throw new Exception("One of the Lists is Null");

                if (list1.Count.Equals(list2.Count))
                {
                    Type type = typeof(T);

                    //For primitive lists
                    if (type.IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        int flag = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (list1.ElementAt(i).Equals(list2.ElementAt(i)))
                                flag++;
                        }
                        if (flag != list1.Count)
                            throw new Exception("Objects values are not same");

                }

                    //For Reference List
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
                        {
                            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
                            {
                                string Object1Value = string.Empty;
                                string Object2Value = string.Empty;

                                Object1Value = type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(list1.ElementAt(i)).ToString();
                                Object2Value = type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(list2.ElementAt(i)).ToString();

                                if (Object1Value != Object2Value)
                                {
                                    throw new Exception("Objects values are not same");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                throw new Exception("Length of lists is not Same");
            }
            else
            throw new Exception("Different type of lists");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
            return true; 
    }
```

this method can be used for both primitive and reference lists.try this method.It will compare type,counts,and members of lists.