# Generic method to compare two lists

Tags: c#, generics

I have 5 sets of `lists` that I need to compare. The requirement is to do this using a generic method.

For example, I have lists `Teacher` and `Student`. `Teacher` has `TeacherId` as its identifier, while `Student` has `StudentId`. Is it possible to create a method that would take in:

```
var result = Compare (teacherA, teacherB, "TeacherId");
var result = Compare (studentA, studentB, "StudentId");
```

It's probably something similar to the top answer here: [How can I create a generic method to compare two list of any type. The type may be a List of class as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480529/how-can-i-create-a-generic-method-to-compare-two-list-of-any-type-the-type-may)

But does it mean I have to create 5 `IComparable` methods per each `list` type? Sorry I'm very new to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing your types should implement one or both of these interfaces: [IEquitable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you just want to see if they are the same. [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to order/sort the instances.

The implementation should be done on the type so `Student` and `Teacher` would both implement these interface(s). If you wanted to compare `Student` to `Teacher` you can implement the same interface using different generic arguments (ie. `class Student : IEquitable<Student>, IEquitable<Teacher>`)

There is no need to use generics here.

Comment: Definitely recommend using the interfaces included in the framework as suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have pretty similar classes and you can create a base class like Person, for example, with property Id and then override it in inherited classes. After that, you can compare Ids.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    // ...
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use interfaces for this.

```
interface ICompareById {
    int Id { get; }
}

class Student : ICompareById {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int StudentId { get { return this.Id; }
}

class Teacher : ICompareById {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int TeacherId { get { return this.Id; }
}

class IdComp : IComparer<ICompareById>
{
    int Compare(ICompareById x, ICompareById y)
    {
        return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x.Id, y.Id);
    }
}
```

To find common elements:

```
teacherList.Intersect(studentList, new IdComp());
```